# Eclipse - Not able to create maven-archetype-webapp Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While creating New Maven > MAVEN-ARCHETYPE-WEBAPP (or infect any provided Arifact of org.apache.maven.archetypes) project on Eclipse Kelper, I am getting following error:

> Could not calculate build plan: 
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

I did requried proxy session and able to add dependencies in POM.XML. Also the enviorment variables  (M2, M2_HOME, JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH) are set.

mvn -version on command prompt is giving required output so maven is working on system.

Windows - Preference - Maven - Office is not selected. And Download options are selected.

Not sure what is missing :(

Kindly advise!

Thanks in advance,
SK

Answer (score 0):

May be this is requried : settings.xml

Step 1: Create specific settings xml file. see [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Configure the local repository if required.

Configure from where the jar files need to be downloaded, using `<mirrors>` or `<profiles>` configuration.

Step 2: Place settings.xml in .m2 folder